# Is it possible to use environment variables with Docker to mark a mounted dir safe?

Tags: git, docker

I have a Docker container that mounts a git directory to perform security scans. Occasionally I receive an error concerning `fatal: detected dubious ownership in repository` because of a delay in ownership propagation to the mounted directory. Solving this is usually done with something along the lines of `git config --global --add safe.directory "<dir>"`, but I want to avoid making changes to the mounted folder.

Has anyone had a successful experience using similar to the following to accomplish adding a safe directory using environment variables?

```bash
export GIT_CONFIG_COUNT=1
export GIT_CONFIG_KEY_0="safe.directory"
export GIT_CONFIG_VALUE_0="<mount point>"
```

I have attempted this combination of env vars without success, but I'm hoping there's just a piece missing that I haven't been able to find, yet.

Comment: I'm not aware of such environment variables used by Git. You state that you "want to avoid making changes to the mounted folder", but `git config --global` does not change the mounted folder, only the `~/.gitconfig` file (which would be inside your Docker container). You could even run this step from your Dockerfile when creating the image

Answer (score -2):

Did a bit more digging and found [this](https://github.com/git/git/blob/756d15923bf6806f94484054873e284728a89c4b/Documentation/config/safe.txt#L15C1-L15C1) as an answer for the version of git I'm using. (TLDR: Not allowed)
For version 2.38.0 and later, however, it is. See [here](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6061601d9f1f1c95da5f9304c319218f7cc3ec75) and [here](https://github.com/git/git/blob/6061601d9f1f1c95da5f9304c319218f7cc3ec75/t/t0033-safe-directory.sh#L23-L28).